# Fixed version number for cached stylesheets and javascript

Tags: cache

Unless i use:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'dazzling-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css?ver=', array(), rand(10,99999), 'all' );
```

Then everytime I visit my site, be it local or live, I see that the version is 4.1 and even though I upload a new stylesheet or js, the browser still sees that 4.1 version.

What's going on? Where is that 4.1 coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4.1 is coming from your WordPress version.

Also you should not append `ver=` to the src manually but use the fourth parameter of [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: Use the **last time the file was changed** as version number. You can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php) (File Modified Time) on the *path* of the file. Example:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'your-handle',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/style.css', # use plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) for plugins
    array( 'dependencies', ), # use [] for PHP 5.4+
    filemtime( get_template_directory().'/assets/style.css' ) # use plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) for plugins
);
```

This will append the *UNIX timestamp* as version number. And it will **stay that way** until you change your stylesheet again. That's the most convenient way I know of. It stays cached in browsers until there's a change. That btw works perfectly with stuff like watch and livereload tasks during development.

And if you ask (in the comments) why WordPress doesn't do that per default, then my answer would be ... *"Uhm, well. WordPress."*

Comment: Can't grasp why this is not the default behaviour in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `?ver=`

4.1 is coming from wordpress, by default it set's a wordpress version